# RecyclerView (GridLayoutManager) no muestra los datos correctamente (Android)

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview

Estoy tratando de mostrar unos datos en un recyclerview (gridLayoutManager).
Los datos se cargan correctamente, pero cuando realizo scroll los empieza a pintar mal.

Algunos datos desaparecen, otros que no se mostraban ahora se muestran.
Imaginando que el problema viniese por la carga de imágenes, he comentado la líneas, con lo cual sólo debe mostrar una cadena.

calendario_item_list.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_calendario"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Calendario_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/niv_flag"
        android:scaleType="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/country_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/niv_flag"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

CalendarioFragment.java
public class CalendarioFragment extends Fragment implements IVista{
    private static final String ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count";
    private int mColumnCount = 3;
    private OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    IPresentador presentador;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    CalendarioRecyclerViewAdapter calendarioRecyclerViewAdapter;
    /**
     * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
     * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
     */
    public CalendarioFragment() {
    }

```
// TODO: Customize parameter initialization
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static CalendarioFragment newInstance(int columnCount) {
    CalendarioFragment fragment = new CalendarioFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT, columnCount);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mColumnCount = getArguments().getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendario_item_list, container, false);
    Context context = view.getContext();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_calendario);
    presentador = new Presentador(this);
    presentador.solicitarDatosVolley();
    calendarioRecyclerViewAdapter = new CalendarioRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity()
            ,presentador.getDatosArray(),mListener);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(calendarioRecyclerViewAdapter);
    if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    } else {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
    }
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnListFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnListFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnListFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

@Override
public Context getApplicationContext() {
    return getActivity().getApplicationContext();
}

@Override
public void refrescarLista() {
    calendarioRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p/>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnListFragmentInteractionListener {
    void onListFragmentInteraction(FivbCalendario item);
}
```

}
CalendarioRecyclerViewAdapter.java
public class CalendarioRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private final List<FivbCalendario> mValues;
private final OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public CalendarioRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context,List<FivbCalendario> items, OnListFragmentInteractionListener listener) {
    mValues = items;
    mListener = listener;
    this.context=context;
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public MiViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendario_item, parent, false);
    MiViewHolder viewHolder = new MiViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MiViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.tvTitulo.setText(mValues.get(position).getTitulo());
   // ImageLoader netImageLoader= ControladorPeticiones.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
    //holder.nivFlag.setImageUrl(Constantes.URL_GENERAL+holder.mItem.getPaisLink(), netImageLoader);
    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (null != mListener) {
                mListener.onListFragmentInteraction(mValues.get(position));
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mValues.size();
}

public class MiViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public final View mView;
    public final TextView tvTitulo;
    public final NetworkImageView nivFlag;


    public MiViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mView = view;
        tvTitulo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
        nivFlag = (NetworkImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.niv_flag);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: No sé exactamente porque se da este tipo de inconveniente, pero en lo personal, me ha pasado cuando intento cambiar alguna propiedad de un widget o poner valores no fijos a ellos dígase, por ejemplo para una imagen poner wrap_content en el height o cambiarle el size o alguna propiedad que juegue con la vista (visibilidad, color, etc...) en el código que recrea la vista. O también, busca si puedes hacer un set de GridLayoutManager a un layout que tiene como padre un RelativeLayout, quizá ahi este el error.

Comment: Gracias @Andrespengineer, he probado con el linearlayout y parece que funciona. Creo que ya sé porque ocurre. Al no cargar ninguna imágen, el textview que se situa debajo de la imagen no sabe donde posicionarse. Al usar el LinearLayout lo ha hecho perfectamente.

Comment: Exacto, suerte.

Comment: Trata de cerrar la pregunta o algo asi, o posteo mi comentario como una respuesta?